# Javascript compare two arrays in map function

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and I'm trying to make a list which is like,

what fruits John, Gaby have got? list. xD

John and Gaby have their own id each and compare those two ids to the Array, Fruits. when fruitId matches to John or Gaby's juiceId, Its John or Gaby's fruits.

John : apple, orrange

Gaby : mango

```
Fruits = [
  {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'apple'},
  {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'orange'},
  {fruitId: 'def', name: 'mango'},
  {fruitId: 'egt', name: 'pineapple'}
]

Juices = [
  {juiceId: 'abc', customer: 'John'},
  {juiceId: 'def', customer: 'Gaby'}
]
```

I think it would be something like this??

```
array.map((list) => {
   <div>// customer's name {list.customer}</div>
   <div>// fruit's name {list.name}</div>
})
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there a particular part that you're having trouble with?

Comment: It would help if you would show us what you want the final output to be.

Comment: Is it correct that both apple and orange have the same `fruitId`?

Comment: The relationships do not make sense.  Why is a FruitId a join on a customer?  And the customer lookups are called "Juices" with "JuiceId" keys?  Then the array maps to HTML instead of creating a List as originally requested.  I'm not sure where to begin to answer this question.  I recommend you clean up the example.

Comment: Your `Fruits` array would be much more usable as `{ abc: ['apple', 'orange'], def: ['mango'], egt: ['pineapple'] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you're going to want is a quick way to reference fruit by `fruitId`. A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of ids to a collection of fruit names would be perfect for this.

To create this, use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const fruitMap = Fruits.reduce((map, { fruitId, name }) => {
  let fruit = map.get(fruitId) || []
  fruit.push(name)
  return map.set(fruitId, fruit)
}, new Map())
```

then you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your *`Juices`* array to something more like your desired output

```
const array = Juices.map(({ juiceId, customer }) => ({
  customer,
  name: (fruitMap.get(juiceId) || []).join(', ')
}))
```

```js
const Fruits =[{"fruitId":"abc","name":"apple"},{"fruitId":"abc","name":"orange"},{"fruitId":"def","name":"mango"},{"fruitId":"egt","name":"pineapple"}]

const Juices = [{"juiceId":"abc","customer":"John"},{"juiceId":"def","customer":"Gaby"}]

const fruitMap = Fruits.reduce((map, { fruitId, name }) => {
  let fruit = map.get(fruitId) || []
  fruit.push(name)
  return map.set(fruitId, fruit)
}, new Map())

const array = Juices.map(({ juiceId, customer }) => ({
  customer,
  name: (fruitMap.get(juiceId) || []).join(', ')
}))

console.info(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you can `reduce` the Juices and `filter` the `Fruits`:

```js
const Fruits = [ {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'apple'}, {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'orange'}, {fruitId: 'def', name: 'mango'}, {fruitId: 'egt', name: 'pineapple'} ]
const Juices = [ {juiceId: 'abc', customer: 'John'}, {juiceId: 'def', customer: 'Gaby'} ]

const r = Juices.reduce((r, {customer, juiceId}) => {
 r[customer] = Fruits.filter(y => y.fruitId == juiceId).map(x => x.name).join(',')
 return r
}, {})

console.log(r)
console.log('John:', r.John)
console.log('Gaby:', r.Gaby)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's pretty simple and understandable approach for this scenario. There could be easy ways to achieve this goal, but this is pretty readable even with and doesn't need advanced javascript approaches.

```
  const Fruits = [
    {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'apple'},
    {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'orange'},
    {fruitId: 'def', name: 'mango'},
    {fruitId: 'egt', name: 'pineapple'}
  ]

  const Juices = [
    {juiceId: 'abc', customer: 'John'},
    {juiceId: 'def', customer: 'Gaby'}
  ]

  let finalArray = []
  Juices.map((juice) => {
    Fruits.map((fruit) => {
      if(juice.juiceId === fruit.fruitId){
        finalArray.push({customer: juice.customer, fruit: fruit.name}) 
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: You should use `forEach` instead of `map`, as `map` creates and returns an array.

Comment: Yeah. should use `forEach`. Assumed that it needed something with `map` as noted in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but this is the best I could comprehend from what you're trying to ask.

```js
function findFruits() {
  var fruits = [
    {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'apple'},
    {fruitId: 'abc', name: 'orange'},
    {fruitId: 'def', name: 'mango'},
    {fruitId: 'egt', name: 'pineapple'}
  ];

  var juices = [
    {juiceId: 'abc', customer: 'John'},
    {juiceId: 'def', customer: 'Gaby'}
  ];
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  juices.forEach(juice => {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var string = `${juice.customer} likes`;
    var matches = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.fruitId === juice.juiceId);

    matches.forEach(match => string += ` ${match.name}`);
    p.innerHTML = string;
    div.appendChild(p);
  });
  
  target.appendChild(div);
}

findFruits();
```

```html
<section id="target"></section>
```